# jquery rain datepicker firefox CSS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my form i got this code from

http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-validation-plugin/

this is working good in **google crome** but **not working in firefox DATE picket not working**

this is my site http://daplonline.in/naukriedu/singup.php

but date picket CSS not showing correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using HTML5 datepicker, which unfortunately not yet implemented on firefox. Take a look at the [w3schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp) to find out.

So for now you might want to switch to some javascript-based solution such as jQuery datepicker, for instance.

Comment: so any other way to add datepicker with exiting validation ?

Comment: Validation will be happy to accept any value that it valid, no matter which datepicker you are using. Like I said, [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) should be ok. Here's another [javascript datepicker](http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php) that should fit in well too.